# If mail's protocol is SMTP, Why does Google mail service start with https?

Tags: https, smtp, protocols, email-client, mail-server

So we can say that when we send an e-mail through a browser, it is sent to a mail server via https, but when we send an e-mail through a program that has a direct connection to the mail server (for example, windows email client) , it is sent via SMTP.?

Comment: SMTP : Simple Mail _TRANSFER_ Protocol. You can access email through a browser. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_agent_(infrastructure).

Comment: So, I can send email through a browser and it is sent to a mail server via https??

Comment: No, read the link. Your web page uses a MUA which then sends it through a MTA or MSA.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is known as [webmail](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#webmail). It's like remote access to a mail client (which can use [SMTP for Submission](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#submission-versus-relay) or a proprietary protocol to communicate with its outgoing mail server). For what it's worth, there is an HTTPS-based [mail access/submission protocol](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#access-protocols): [JSON Meta Application Protocol (JMAP)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#json-meta-application-protocol). For email to work, only mail-server-to-mail-server communication [needs to be standardized](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#standardization). The [Extended Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (ESMTP)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#extended-simple-mail-transfer-protocol) for Relay is used for this purpose.